# Select Picker Is Not Showing When i call Using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am Calling this File using Ajax But this file is displaying but without selectpicker, I don't see any error if anyone can help me?

Bootstrap Selectpicker Will Show Timing From Monday to Sunday

**IF condition** is used to check whether this time is present in the database or not if present check the checkbox and show the time in bootstrap Selectpciker

*All the condition displaying in this file is important I cant remove them*

```
 <?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors",1);
    require_once'configuration/config.php';


    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
    $startTime = strtotime(date("H:i:s",strtotime('00:00:00')));
    $endTime = strtotime(date('H:i:s',strtotime('23:59:00')));

    if(isset($_POST['doc_id'])){
            $days = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'];
            $doc_id ='921007GAURAV984934'; 
            $hp_id = 'INRJAPPO2E381F220220';
            $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM tb_doc_loc WHERE doc_id=? AND hp_id= ?');
            $stmt->bind_param('ss',$doc_id,$hp_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $res = $stmt->get_result();
            while($row = $res->fetch_array()){
                $data =  $row['datas'];
            }
            $datas = explode(',',$data);
            $chunk = array_chunk($datas,5);
        for($i=0;$i<count($chunk);$i++): ?>
            <?php if($chunk[$i][0] == $days[$i]): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class=" form-check" style="margin-top: 7px;">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="edit_days" value="<?php echo $chunk[$i][0]?>" checked="checked">
                                <?php echo $chunk[$i][0]?> 
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label>Morning Timings</label><br>
                                        <select class="selectpicker " id="<?php echo $chunk[$i][0]?>_Morning_time" title="Select Timings" multiple data-max-options="2"   data-size="5">
                                            <?php for($k=$startTime;$k<=$endTime;$k = $k + 30*60): ?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo date('H:i',$k);?>"<?php if($chunk[$i][1] == date('H:i',$k) ||$chunk[$i][2] == date('H:i',$k)){echo"Selected";}?> ><?php echo date('H:i',$k)?></option>
                                            <?php endfor; ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label>Evening Timings</label><br><!-- line 73 -->
                                        <select class="selectpicker" id="<?php echo $chunk[$i][0]?>_Evening_time" title="Select Timings" multiple data-max-options="2"  data-size="5">
                                            <?php for($k=$startTime;$k<=$endTime;$k = $k + 30*60): ?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo date('H:i',$k);?>"<?php if($chunk[$i][3] == date('H:i',$k) ||$chunk[$i][4] == date('H:i',$k)){echo"Selected";}?> ><?php echo date('H:i',$k)?></option>
                                            <?php endfor; ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>          
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endfor;?>
        <?php for($j=$i;$j<count($days);$j++): ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class=" form-check" style="margin-top: 7px;">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="edit_days" value="<?php echo $days[$j]?>"><?php echo $days[$j]?>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label >Morning Start</label><br>
                                <select class="selectpicker " id="<?php echo $days[$j]?>_Morning_time" title="Select Timings" multiple data-max-options="2"  data-size="5">
                                <?php for($k=$startTime;$k<=$endTime;$k = $k + 30*60): ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo date('H:i',$k)?>"><?php echo date('H:i',$k)?></option>
                                <?php endfor; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label >Morning End</label><br>
                                <select class="selectpicker " id="<?php echo $days[$j]?>_Evening_time" title="Select Timings" multiple data-max-options="2"  data-size="5" >
                                <?php for($k=$startTime;$k<=$endTime;$k = $k + 30*60): ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo date('H:i',$k)?>"><?php echo date('H:i',$k)?></option>
                                <?php endfor; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endfor; 
    }
    ?>
```

output of this model:

[image: Image Of Modal]

SelectPicker is displaying when I use inspect element on the main page but problem what I find it having CSS property 
`.bootstrap-select > select.bs-select-hidden, select.bs-select-hidden, select.selectpicker {
    display: none !important;
}`
[[image: Image Of Inspect Element][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptLHw.png)
why I don't know

Comment: can you show your css and also the devtools screen shot?

Comment: Can you show how you are calling datepicker function in jquery?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I am not using Datepicker I am Using Bootstrap SelectPicker

Comment: ok can you show me code for SelectPicker?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay The above code is that file which i fetching using this  $('.editModals').on('click',function(){
   docId = $(this).attr('id');
   $.ajax({
    url:'doc_timings2.php',
    data:{doc_id:docId},
    type:'POST',
    success:function(data){
     $('#display').html(data);
    }
   });

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay that the link of page http://igaurav.co.in/starRatingSystem/first.php

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the answer after reading documentation again and again that I have to call selectpicker function after displaying the Ajax output.
Ajax Call:-

```
$('.editModals').on('click',function(){
            docId = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                url:'doc_timings2.php',
                data:{doc_id:docId},
                type:'POST',
                success:function(data){
                    $('#display').html(data);
                    $('select').selectpicker();// That's the function
                }
            });
```